# How to check Child forms are open or not?

Tags: c#, winforms, mdiparent

I have MDI parent form. Under this MDI Parent there are lots of MDI Child form. How I check child form are open or not?

```
            foreach (Form frm in this.MdiChildren)
            {
                if (frm == null)
                {
                   //code.....
                }
            }
```

But this is not working.

Comment: What do you meant by open or not? Check `frm.Visible`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you close the child forms, they should drop out of the `MdiChildren` collection.

So you can just use this:

```
if (!MdiChildren.Any())
{
    // all child forms closed
}
```

If you've just hidden the child forms, not closed them, you can use:

```
if (MdiChildren.All(c => !c.Visible))
{
    // all child forms hidden/closed
}
```